# How to make a small application in ColdFusion using Wirebox 1.6 standalone?

Tags: coldfusion, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, aop, coldbox

I am new to Wirebox 1.6 framework. I have to create a small application, in ColdFusion 10, using the Wirebox 1.6 framework. I have downloaded Wirebox 1.6 Standalone, put it into my webroot, and tested the code below successfully:

```
<cfscript>
wirebox = createObject("component","wirebox.system.ioc.Injector").init();
</cfscript>
<cfdump var="#wirebox#">
```

However, I need some sample code that demonstrates the working of the Wirebox framework in an application.Are there any links that provide sample code to run, that will help me understand wirebox?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to some [sample code for Wirebox](https://github.com/murpg/wireboxstandaloneaop/blob/master/Application.cfc) working as a standalone unit.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to ask on the ColdBox Google Group:
http://groups.google.com/group/coldbox

Comment: i asked but did not get any solution or sample code to prepare small coldfusion application, any other ideas please....